# merging data frames with merge() and blanks - format issue

Tags: r, merge

I'd like to add information from one data frame to another, from `dfadd` to `dfmaster`, whilst keeping the order of the rows in `dfmaster`.

I've attempted using merge() but it changes the order of the rows in `dfmaster`. And the order is key here. Is there a data.table() or tidyverse() way of handling this?

Thanks!

```
# Data
dfmaster <- data.frame(variable_name=c("Blood_sugar","","","Blood_pressure","","Pulse",""),variable_level=c("high","medium","low","high","low","high","low"),variable_defin=c("baseline, lab","","","baseline, measured","","baseline, measured",""))
dfadd <- data.frame(variable_name=c("Blood_sugar","Blood_pressure","Pulse","Breakfast","Rest"),centre_names1=c("ST","FD","","QW",""),centre_names2=c("","HF","","",""),centre_names3=c("","LD","","",""),one_or_more=c("one","more","","one",""))


# Goal 
dfgoal <- data.frame(variable_name=c("Blood_sugar","","","Blood_pressure","","Pulse",""),variable_level=c("high","medium","low","high","low","high","low"),variable_defin=c("baseline, lab","","","baseline, measured","","baseline, measured",""),centre_names1=c("ST","","","FD","","",""),centre_names2=c("","","","FD","","",""),centre_names3=c("","","","LD","","",""),one_or_more=c("more","","","more","","",""))


# Attempt 
dfmaster <- merge(dfmaster,dfadd,by="variable_name", all.x=T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a small error in your `dfgoal`... on `Blood_sugar`, "one_or_more" should be "one" (according to `dfadd`), and not "more".

Please check if the code below is the answer for you.

```
library(dplyr)
dfmaster %>% 
  #perform left join
  left_join(dfadd) %>% 
  #tidy all the emtpy factors to NA (remove if not desired)
  mutate_if(is.factor, funs(factor(replace(., .=="", NA))))

#    variable_name variable_level     variable_defin centre_names1 centre_names2 centre_names3 one_or_more
# 1    Blood_sugar           high      baseline, lab            ST          <NA>          <NA>         one
# 2                        medium               <NA>          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>        <NA>
# 3                           low               <NA>          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>        <NA>
# 4 Blood_pressure           high baseline, measured            FD            HF            LD        more
# 5                           low               <NA>          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>        <NA>
# 6          Pulse           high baseline, measured          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>        <NA>
# 7                           low               <NA>          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>        <NA>
```